# Use jquery inside html tag?

Tags: jquery, onclick

How can I insert jquery inside an html tag like using it in `onclick`. For example how can I insert this jquery function inside html?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  $("p").slideToggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button>Toggle between slide up and slide down for a p element</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Does the code you have now not work?

Comment: You should probably read some of the jQuery tutorials: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Comment: Using in-line event handlers makes for exponentially-difficult maintenance of your web-site, you should *really* strive to avoid that where possible, and keep your behaviour out of your mark-up.

Comment: @DavidThomas, Thanks for the advice, you are absolutely right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the body of your function directly in the `onclick` attribute of the `button` tag works.

```
<button onclick='$("p").slideToggle();'>
    Toggle between slide up and slide down for a p element
</button>
```

However, I think the way you have it is a preferable way to do it, since it takes advantage of the `$(document).ready` function.